# Laravel how to display the key values of array in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

In my `laravel`-application, I create an array like this:

```
$positions = Position::whereHas('jobs')
    ->with('jobs')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->mapSpread(function ($position) {
         return $position->jobs->where('job_status_id', '=', '2')->pluck('industry');
     })
```

this returns an array, which looks like this: (I've made a dd($positions))

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1280 ▼
#items: array:9 [▼
  "Engineer" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1279 ▶}
  "Analyst" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1274 ▼
     #items: array:1 [▼
       0 => App\Industry {#1294 ▶}
     ]
   }
  "Receptionist" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1304 ▶}
  "Programmer" => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1306 ▼
     #items: array:2 [▶]
   }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to display the key values and the amount of jobs the key value has in my `blade` view - for example "Programmer (2)"

I tried to do this:

```
@foreach($positions as $k => $v)

  @foreach ($v as $key => $value)
        {{ $value->name }}
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

but this only returns the name of the industry, like for example "IT" or "Construction" (which I get from the Industry relation)

So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You try count() method for a collection

```php
@foreach($positions as $k => $v)
 <div>{{ $k }} ({{ $v->count() }})</div>
@endforeach
```

Reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-count

Answer (score 0):

Count the element in the for loop and display it like this in the view

```
@foreach($positions as $k => $v)

  @foreach ($v as $key => $value)
        {{ $value->name }} {{ count($value->toArray()) }}
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Remove the `toArray()` if it gives error.